# Constraints, 3 FKs with One Null, SQL Server 2012, DB Theory Only

Tags: sql-server, database-design, constraints

*please read my disclaimers before down-voting*

I have the following table.

```
Inventory (InventoryID (PK), LocationID (FK), ProductID (FK), BookID (FK), Quantity)
```

My current constraints enforce that either the `BookID` or `ProductID` cannot be null for a given row, and that `LocationID` cannot be null.

I want a constraint that enforces the following: LocationID + ProductID + BookID must be unique. In other words, I do not want a book or product to show up twice at the same location.

To be clear, for any record, `ProductID` or `BookID` can be null, but not both, and `LocationID` cannot be null.

Disclaimers:

1. This question is based entirely on personal curiosity. Results will not in any way impact a graded assignment. I am just curious
2. Anyone answering this should be experienced enough to assume the excluded details
3. I am only looking for a possible constraint, or similar solution. I am not looking for a rework

Comment: SQL Server 2013 ???

Comment: @GordonLinoff it's what all the cool kids use.

Comment: Sorry, 2012. Typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SQL Server, a unique constraint/index only allows one `NULL` value.  So, I think you can do what you want with filtered index:

```
create unique index unq_inventory_LocationID_ProductID_BookID
    on inventory(LocationID, ProductID, BookID)
    where LocationID is not null and ProductID is not null and BookID is not null;
```

Your `check` constraints should take care of the other conditions.

EDIT:

Ah, I see.  You need two unique constraints:

```
create unique index unq_inventory_LocationID_ProductID
    on inventory(LocationID, ProductID)
    where LocationID is not null and ProductID is not null;

create unique index unq_inventory_LocationID_BookID
    on inventory(LocationID, BookID)
    where LocationID is not null and BookID is not null;
```

Or, if you prefer one unique index, you can use a computed column:

```
alter table inventory add BookId_or_ProductId as (coalesce(BookId, ProductId));

create unique index unq_inventory_LocationID_BookID_ProductId
    on inventory(LocationID, BookId_or_ProductId);
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to provide a constructive answer. Please forgive my naiveté in my follow-up question.There will be no record where all 3 fields will meet the not null condition. LocationID will never be null, but in any given record either ProductID or BookID will be null. No record will exist where ProductID AND BookID are not null. Will this index still work?

Comment: Cool thanks for the additional options. I went with the two unique indexes, but I'm going to keep that coalesce idea in my pocket. Thanks again.